# What is gsl::multi_span to be used for?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

The C++ core guidelines mention spans, not "multi-spans". But - I see that Microsoft's GSL implementation has a [`multi_span` class](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/multi_span)

```
template <
    typename ValueType,
    std::ptrdiff_t FirstDimension,
    std::ptrdiff_t... RestDimensions
>
class multi_span { ... };
```

So, obviously this is some sort of a multi-dimensional version of `gsl::span`. But what is that supposed to mean? Why do we need this multi-dimensional span, or rather - when would we use it? I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, it is a span over contiguous piece of memory, which represents multidimensional array.

Here is an example of use:

```
int data[6] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
multi_span<int, 2, 3> span{data, 6};
std::cout << span[1][1] << '\n'; //Outputs 4
```

From the linked source, it seems, that it also supports runtime bounds, but I am not sure about proper syntax for those.

Comment: I wonder why do we need a separate class for it? Seems like it is possible to design `span` in a way that it is applicable to both one and multiple dimensions.

Comment: @Mikhail it is not in GSL, it is a Microsoft own extention. Probably there weren't concensus on how multidimensional spans should be implemented, or there were some problems with them, so they did not make into GSL. Apparently Microsoft decided that it still wants them, or rolled own proof of concept implementation for testing, so, to not break existing span class, it made a new one.

Comment: there's probably some semantic value in having a separation between a single dimensional vs. multidimensional span.