# How to wrap multi level raw pointers to give it container semantics

Tags: c++

How can I wrap `T**` to give it `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` semantics?  All solutions I have found so far address a single dimension.

The use case is to pass both `T**` and `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` to a function that consumes matrix data.

```
template<class RowIt>
void foo(RowIt rowFirst, RowIt rowLast) {
    // size doesn't handle dynamically allocated arrays        
    size_t columns = std::size(*rowFirst);     

    // second layer std::begin, std::end and iterator doesn't 
    // work for dynamically allocated arrays
    for (; rowFirst != rowLast; ++rowFirst) {
       auto colFirst = std::begin(rowFirst);
       auto colLast = std::end(rowFirst);
       for (; colFirst != colLast; ++colFirst) {
           // processing logic
       }
    }
}
```

I attempted to extend the single dimension solution to multi dimension.  The problem I run into is

```
template<class T>
class view {
   T* data_;
};
```

`view<view<T>>` can't be composed from `view<T>`.

Comment: How about just overloading the function? One that takes a vector of vectors as argument, and another that takes the pointer to pointer (and dimensions of course)?

Comment: What do you mean with "view<view<T>> can't be composed from view<T>"?

Comment: To make life easy you shouldn't have a `T**` or a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`.  Use a single `std::vector<T>` and make its size `dim1 * dim2 * ...`.  Now all your elements are guaranteed contiguous in memory and you and it is much easier to grab different slices.  You can encapsulate this in it's own class and use the `operator()` for array like access.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Overloading doesn't solve the problem though.  Eventually, the two types will need to be synthesized into one for the shared algorithms.

Comment: @MaxLanghof view<view<T>> implies data_ is view<T>* which doesn't exist.

Comment: @NathanOliver Both types are inherited.  the current task is to write the algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't exist? [The compiler will just instantiate the template...](https://godbolt.org/g/ZQj43t)

Comment: Is the data pointed to ever going to change in size (during the lifetime of the wrapper?)  Also, how much of the functionality of `std::vector` do you actually _need_ (roughly)?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a partial specialisation for nested `views`.

```
template<class T>
class view {
   using pointer = T*;
   pointer data_;
};

template<class T>
class view<view<T>> {
   using pointer = typename view<T>::pointer *;
   pointer data_;
};
```

Or specify `view::pointer` via a traits class, if it is the only divergence from the primary template

```
template<class T>
class view_traits {
   using pointer = T*;
};

template<class T>
class view_traits<view<T>> {
   using pointer = typename view<T>::pointer *;
};

template<class T>
class view {
   using pointer = typename view_traits<T>::pointer;
   pointer data_;
   // other members use T unchanged
};
```

Comment: That means all the code I put in the primary template would have to be copied to the specialization, right?

Comment: @CandyChiu That's what the second suggestion avoids

Comment: view_trait resolves the nested type problem, but doesn't provide the container semantics at the nested level.  for example, `iterator begin();` has to return a view of T* instead of T* in order to provide container semantics.

Comment: Hmm yes. It's probably easier to start from the first method, and see if there is too much duplication. Have a look at [`gsl::multi_span`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201524/what-is-gslmulti-span-to-be-used-for) is that the type of thing you are trying to do?

Comment: No.  multi_span turns a single dimension data into multiple dimension.  I am handed a multi dimension dynamically allocated array.