# c++ pointers using vector class

Tags: c++

Well, I'm learning to work with vector class combined with pointers and I have had the following problem:

```
vector<vector<vector<float>>*> t;
vector<vector<float>> p = { { 6.2,7,8 } };
vector<vector<float>> g = { { 6.6,5.8,9 } };
t.push_back(&p);
t.push_back(&g)
cout << "Print address: " << t[0] << endl; // works well, I see the address
cout << "Print address: " << t[1] << endl; // works  well, I see the address

//However, when I tried to access the content I didn't:

cout << "Print content: " << *t[0][0][0] << endl;

//My expectation is see 6.2
```

Comment: You only need two `[0]`. Also my guess is, that this is just a simple precedence problem, try `(*t[0])[0]` or `t[0]->operator[](0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<vector<vector<float>>*> t;
```

`t` is vector of pointers to 2D vector of float.

Therefore `*t[0][0][0]` (which means dereferencing the inner most vector, which is not a pointer) should really be `(*t[0])[0][0]` which means dereferencing the outer most vector.

Answer (score 0):

t[0] or `vector<vector<float>>*` is a pointer to address (see `t[0]`). Because it's a pointer u use "->" `t[0]->at(i)` as an operator to access methods such as `at()`, which returns the indexed i'th element. Because there's one more vector incepted (`vector<float>`) that's not a pointer. In our case you do dot "." `t[0]->at().at()`

```
vector<vector<vector<float>>*> t;
vector<vector<float>> p = { { 6.2, 7, 8 } };
vector<vector<float>> g = { { 6.6, 5.8, 9 } };
   
t.push_back(&p);
t.push_back(&g);
    
cout << "t[0] el addr -> " << t[0] << endl; 
cout << "t[1] el addr -> " << t[1] << endl; 

cout << "Content t[0]->[0].[0] => " << t[0]->at(0).at(0) << endl;
```

Comment: You should explain your answer rather than just writing code :)

Comment: I gave him the code that returns the expected result so it's more exciting for the OP to reverse engineer what is already written. But I get what you mean. I personally like to see the code first and then figure it out, by reading other answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Well, I'm learning to work if vector class combined with pointer

Hmm, that already sounds suspicious. There are lots of undesirable coding patterns using vectors-of-pointers.

> `vector<vector<vector<float>>*> t;`

Yeah, so... don't write that. I mean, I'm not *forbidding* you to write that, but it's highly unlikely that this is what you want to write. Why would you want to allocate and maintain a large number of vectors - your 'inner' vectors? As well as a large number of vectors-of-vectors, your mid-level vectors? And finally, why would you want to track the allocation of the outer dimension of your structure - the pointers-to-vectors-of-vectors?

If you want a 3-dimensional structure of `floats`, either write a 3D tensor class, or allocate a single large array for all elements of your tensor, then use a `gsl::multispan` from [this Guidelines Support Library implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL) to access your data as a 3-dimensional container, and using triplets of indices:

```
float data[12] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
multi_span<int, 2, 3, 2> span{data, 12};
std::cout << span[1][1][1] << '\n'; // Should output 8
```

See also: [What is gsl::multi_span to be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45201524/1593077)